# Determine if the user is reloading the current page in onunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to determine if the user is reloading the current page from within the events `window.onunload` or `window.onbeforeunload`?

I need to determine if the user is reloading the page and if they are stop my code from deleting a cookie.

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

    // How can I detect a page refresh?
    if (USER_NOT_REFRESHING)
        $.removeCookie("my_session", { path: '/' });
    else {
        // user is refreshing
    }

}
```

Comment: you can not detect it

Comment: I'm wondering what the use case is -- why do you want the cookie to be deleted just because the user is leaving the page? Wouldn't you want to maintain their session in case they return in a minute? Otherwise, what's the point of using a session?

Comment: You cannot detect a page that hasn't loaded, but you can use a load Event with a session or cookie and see if the same page was already loaded.

Comment: On page unload set the cookie expiration time to say 5 seconds, that is enough to see if he is reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The browser only indicates the user is leaving, not why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [**PerformanceNavigation API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation)

So, if the browser supports performance navigation, then you can check for reload by doing:

```
if(performance.navigation.type===1) {
// it's a reload
}
```

The above method may not work for code snippets